# link a list element to a set/list of library documents same farm

Tags: document, links-list

i´m new to SharePoint 2013 and I would like to have a list where each element could have one or more documents from a document library.

I have to define a folder where all element's list documents are stored?
be aware about security of each document?
how can I provide uploading document from the element list edit form?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You could use a content type named DOCUMENT SET in a document library.

regard